# How does getting a new face help?

Tags: logans-run

In a scene in Logan's Run, Logan advises a fellow Sandman, after a near-scrape with runners, to

> get a new face- they know you now

but the Sandmen wear distinct uniforms (no plainclothes division). Whether or not he got a new face, a runner could spot them from a mile away. What good does altering one's face do?

Comment: If your face looked like mine, you wouldn't be asking! {rimshot}

Answer (score 5):

The children living in the Cathedral aren't *runners*, they're cubs, basically feral children who live outside of the central plaza. The full quote (from [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Logan's-Run.html)) is

> **SANDMAN** (embarrassed): *I lost a Runner in Cathedral.*
>
> **LOGAN:** *How come?*
>
> **SANDMAN:** *Ran into some Cubs I couldn't manage. (as they stare) One of them cut me bad...*
>
> **FRANCIS:** (with anger) *CUBS!*
>
> **SANDMAN** (shrug): *On my way to the New You for repairs.*
>
> **LOGAN:** *Get yourself a new face while you're at it They know you now.*

The cubs seem *generally* wary of sandmen, but I think we can assume that they would be more likely to attack someone they recognised as having attacked them before, or whom they had attacked before without getting themselves shot.